# Launch Image/Screen for iOS with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, image, xcode6, launch

The final step of my first iphone app (Xcode 6) is to add a launch (splash) screen.  I copied a 640x960 (iphone 5 ios8) into my images.xcassets file, into the LauchImage space.  I copied into the 2x location (for iPhone Portrait iOS 7,8).  I am only running this development app on a single phone so won't need to support all the various screens/sizes.

Apparently, just dragging the image into the .xcassets file/LaunchImage isn't sufficient.  I still have only a one sec black screen flash while my app is loading, and no launch screen.  Is there another step or two needed here?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

In your app settings General page try setting the Launch Image Source to "Use Asset Catalog".
[image: Use Asset Catalog]

Comment: In the General Settings/Launch Images Source, it doesn't provide the option to "Use Asset Catalog".  It only allows "Launchimage" or "Don't use asset catalogs".  It currently has "Launchimage" checked.

Comment: Also, the Launch Screen File is blank.  Typing "Launchimage" or "Launchscreen" in this field did not work.